# Python. Как разделить список по словам?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется список, у которого один элемент, и это текст с 5-8 словами. Вопрос: как вывести каждое слово этого элемента по отдельности?

Я попытался, чтобы побуквенно складывался до пробела, выводил это слово и шёл дальше.

```
def chek(text):
    chek_nummber = 0
    buffer = ''
    for i in text:
        chek_nummber += 1
        if i != ' ':
            buffer += i
        else:
            print(buffer)
            buffer = ''
    print(buffer)
```

Comment: Метод split() возвращает список всех слов в строке

Comment: Ваш код вроде работает, вопрос то у вас в чём? )

Comment: код та работает да, но место где я его использую в него добавляются много переменных и обращений к разным функциям. после чего код становится очень большим.

Comment: @Интик спасибо что ты подсказал метод split() я про него забыл "face_palm"

Answer (score 1):

Ниже приведен аналог вашей функции, но лучше используйте split.

```
def ToWords(text: str):
    has_word = False
    word     = str()
    result   = list()
    for char in text:
        if char.isspace():
            if has_word:
                result.append(word)
                word     = str()
                has_word = False
        else:
            word    += char
            has_word = True
    if has_word:
        result.append(word)
    return result

print(ToWords("Hello, world.     \n  I'am Charlotte!"))
```

Вывод:

```
['Hello,', 'world.', "I'am", 'Charlotte!']
```

Comment: а почему вы пишите `str()` и `list()`, а не `""` и `[]`?

Comment: @Danis Человек может привык к нормальному объектному языку ))

Answer (score 0):

```
f = ['один два три четыре пять']

for i in f:
    a = i.split()
for i in a:
    print(i)

Вывод:

один
два
три
четыре
пять
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text = ['один два три четыре пять']
print(text.split(), sep='\n')


Вывод:

один
два
три
четыре
пять
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'